# Restrict list view visibility to a group

Tags: list-view

Is it possible to restrict the visibility of a globally visible list view to a group of users. I want certain users not to see several list views that are shared to every user in the system. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are global, then you can't. I suggest you edit them and change the global view to one where you select the viewers (leaving out the people/groups who shouldn't have access.

Answer (score 0):

I think only way is removing "Manage Public List Views" permissions on the profile coz profile permissions will be taken high priority. For more details you can refer to 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187425&language=en_US